# Sum list of numbers

Tags: oracle, sum

I have the following code below that generates a list of numbers and its working.

Instead of the list of numbers I would like to generate the sum(). This case would be 1+2+3+4+5 = 15 where 15 is the only output I want but I can't seem to get this to work. Any help would would be appreciated.

```
WITH t(n) AS ( 
   SELECT 1 from dual UNION ALL 
   SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 5 ) 
SELECT * FROM t;
```

Comment: What is wrong with `select sum(n) from <subquery>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already seen how to calculate sum of these numbers.

However, why are you creating a **list** of numbers while the only thing you're interested in is their **sum**?

Generally speaking, if *list* starts with `1` and ends with an `n`, formula is `n(n + 1) / 2`. Rewritten to Oracle SQL:

```
SQL> select &&par_number * (&&par_number + 1) / 2 as result from dual;
Enter value for par_number: 5

    RESULT
----------
        15

SQL> undefine par_number
SQL> select &&par_number * (&&par_number + 1) / 2 as result from dual;
Enter value for par_number: 3

    RESULT
----------
         6

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap `n` in `SUM`:

```
WITH t(n) AS ( 
   SELECT 1 from dual UNION ALL 
   SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 5 ) 
SELECT SUM(n) FROM t;
```

But a simpler way to generate numbers (and then sum them, if you want) would be:

```
select SUM(level) from dual connect by level <=5
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use sum(*) in SQL but you can sum all of the values in n:

```
WITH t(n) AS (SELECT 1 from dual UNION ALL
SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 5)  
SELECT sum(n) FROM t;
```

I am assuming you already know this though?

Answer (score 1):

If the only purpose of that list is to get the sum of numbers from 1 to `n` then use formula: `sum(1..n) = n*(n+1)/2`.

```
create function f_sum_1_n(n number)
  return number
as
  pragma udf;
begin
  return n*(n+1)/2;
end;/
```

```
select f_sum_1_n(5)
from dual
```

| F_SUM_1_N(5) |
| --- |
| 15 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E0sA_wHA)

Or the same with SQL Macro for 21c+ to avoid context switches.

```
create function f_sum_1_n_macro(n number)
  return varchar2
  sql_macro(scalar)
as
begin
  return q'[f_sum_1_n_macro.n*(f_sum_1_n_macro.n+1)/2]';
end;/
```

```
select sum(f_sum_1_n_macro(val))
from t
```

| SUM(F_SUM_1_N_MACRO(VAL)) |
| --- |
| 15 |

```
select *
from dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
  format => '+PROJECTION'
)
```

```
 PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT 
 :-----------------
 SQL_ID  fv39qapvdaf6s, child number 1 
 ------------------------------------- 
 select sum(f_sum_1_n_macro(val)) from t 
   
 Plan hash value: 2966233522 
   
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 | Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |       |       |     3 (100)|          | 
 |   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     3 |            |          | 
 |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   
 Column Projection Information (identified by operation id): 
 ----------------------------------------------------------- 
   
    1 - (#keys=0) SUM("VAL"*("VAL"+1)/2)[22] 
    2 - (rowset=256) "VAL"[NUMBER,22]
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lNEByndj)